# Code 206 Partial Content and lynx: Can't access startfile

Tags: lynx, cloudflare

I'm trying to download a page that uses cloudflare. I have tried with `curl` with no luck, now i'm trying with `lynx`. I'm able to get into the main webpage of this site and certain other pages but now I'm trying to get to the search that this page is using, and since it is returning

```
Alert!: HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content

lynx: Can't access startfile https://www.pccomponentes.com/listado/ajax?idShops%5B%5D=0&page=0&order=price-desc&gtmTitle=Tarjetas%20Gr%C3%A1ficas&idFamilies%5B%5D=6
```

nothing is showed there. If I open that URL with a browser, it works ok.

Why is it not working?

Comment: I get something when I curl this URL, namely a page that says things like *Checking your browser before accessing pccomponentes.com*, *DDoS protection by Cloudflare*, and perhaps most importantly, **Please enable Cookies and                                  reload the page**. I don't know how to configure cookies for `curl`, but this seems to be your problem.

Comment: I know how to save cooking with curl, i have done that already and it is working in other pages , but not when it returns 206 partial content.